# How to skip "This project is using version xxx of android gradle plugin, which is incompatible with this version of android studio" dialog?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

When ever updating each and every incremental build of Android Studio Canary, the below dialog appears and asks to update gradle plugin. The asked version is just a patch from **`7.0.0.-alpha02`** to **`7.0.0.-alpha03`**

[image]

How can I fix this, can anything be done to skip this kind of silly updates when updating android studio?

Comment: as said gradle plugin needs to be updated to work with this version of Android Studio

Comment: why is it just a patch?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't skip this and sometimes it gets error and problems to your project.

If this happens to you, you can try upgrading the Gradle version in the dependencies of your buildscript:

classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha04" or a newest version

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too.

Try this. Search the project globally for `7.0.0.-alpha02`, and replace with `7.0.0.-alpha03`.

[image: Dependencies.kt in buildSrc dir]